# Giving a function multiple cores to work with rather than 1

Tags: dask

Let's say I have 8 cores, and I want to run 2 functions that each use 4 cores (ML models for example), what is the best way to set this up. I cannot find examples such as this in the doc.

Eg let's say sklearn random forest to keep things simple.

```
def our_func(X, y):
    return RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=4).fit(X, y)

a = client.submit(our_func, X1, y1)  
b = client.submit(our_func, X2, y2)
```

how can I make sure that the funcs will use 4 different processes each?

Comment: Note that dask has an integration with joblib, so that you may be able to do this without client.submit at all.

Comment: Wouldn't this be fixed by configuring workers to have 4 cores each at the time that the cluster is created/initiated?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm new to Dask and wanted to know if this could be elegantly done (since I can't find anything in the doc)